# ObjectBox count with distinct

Tags: count, distinct, objectbox

I have a CAR entity with a BRAND property coded with a `long`.
I want to know how many distinct BRANDS there are in the table.
With SqlLite/GreenDAO I do that with

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT column) FROM tablename
```

With ObjectBox I arrived to

```
long[] ids = App.shBox.query().build().property(Car_.companyId).distinct().findLongs();
```

and the length of the array is my result.
There is a better way to obtain the same result?
I'd expect to use

```
App.shBox.query().build().property(Car_.companyId).distinct().count();
```

but it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great idea. Here's a [feature request](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/434) to track progress on this.